# Sonarqube 4.0 unable to generate report

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to do sonar analysis on one of my projects but I am facing some issue when it comes to the very end of the mvn sonar:sonar command I am using Java 7 with maven 2.2.1 and sonar 4.0
The error reported on screen is cannot execute sonar
Unable to execute maven plugin.

And further the trace says     Org.apache.maven.lifecycle.lifecycleExecutionException: cannot execute sonar

```
 Caused by:org.apache.maven.plugin.mojoExecutionException: cannot execute sonar
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException:unable to execute maven plugin.
Caused by org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException:Unable to execute Maven 2 plugin
Caused by Java.lang.reflect.InvoacationTargetException

Caused by java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
```

Comment: 4.0 is from Nov. 2013. The current version is 6.4 and the current LTS version is 5.6.6. You should put serious thought into upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

It can depend on your exact `mvn` command, especially when used with a multithreading option (`mvn -T4`).

The firs thing to test, as mentioned in this [versions-maven-plugin issue 40](https://github.com/mojohaus/versions-maven-plugin/issues/40), is to see if the latest maven would avoid this issue.
Check out [Maven 3.5.0](https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.5.0/release-notes.html), to see if this is a maven core issue, or a Sonar plugin one.